# Imported Project DotNet.Props Was Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

Someone please.  Anyone.  I've been fretting over this issue the last two days. I've read other issues that are similar.  But they are not exact.

The error message is: 
    The imported project

*"C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\1.04\Microsft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found.  Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.*

I am trying to run an Angular2 ASP.NET core app developed using Visual Studio Express For Web 2015 that was working perfectly, before I installed Visual Studio 2017.  I think the issues is the program is looking for a version of .NET core that somehow got removed.  Here is my proj.json

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-Angular2-b6820071-fb17-4201-b6fd-407054319783",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-
 final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
  "type": "build"
},
  "tools": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
    "scripts": {
          "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", 
    "gulp 
    min" 
    ],
      "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder 
%publish:OutputPath% 
--framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
    },
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.1"
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the error message I receive when attempting to merely open the application:

[image]

And here is the error message in the console when attempting to run the program:

[image]

I'd appreciate your guidance. 
Thanks,
CM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue using `project.json` based projects in VS 2015, you need to add a `global.json` file with the following contents at the solution level (directory hierarchy at or above `project.json`):

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177"
  }
}
```

Replace `1.0.0-preview2-1-003177` with the latest 1.0.0 preview 2 version installed on your machine - you can find this version as a subfolder of `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk`.

Comment: Hey Martin thanks for responding.  I really need to resolve this.  What exactly do I need to do.  I tried inserting a global.json file at the solution level with the content you provided above and I received the "The project is configured to use .NET Core SDK version 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177 which is not installed" error message indicating that version wasn't installed which it isn't.  But I then tried, "version": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003131", which is indeed installed, and received the same error message.  In the project.json there is a dependency for "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",

Comment: update the project.json dependency to a non-prerelease version. 1.0.5 is the current one.

Comment: I have 1.0.4 installed.  Can I use that?  If so, what would the updated project.json look like?  I'd appreciate it.

Comment: 1.0.4 runtime? yes that works as well. just update the microsoft.netcore.app string and then use the VS integrated package management UI

Comment: Alertnatively, use VS 2017 to create a new csproj-based project and add the source files to it. Or use the Migration included in VS 2017.
The project.json tooling is deprecated and no longer supported