# MSBuild error building ASP.Net Core 1.0 project - Imported project was not found

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

Trying to build a ASP.Net Core 1.0 project (.xproj) on a Build machine. Project built in VS2015. .Net Core is installed on the Build machine. I get this build error

The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirmed that path in the  declaration is correct, and file exists on disk.

Tried the suggestion from this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046483/imported-project-dotnet-props-was-not-found)but doesn't help.

I can confirm that the path and file do exist on the build server.

Also tried passing MS Build Argument /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.

Any leads highly appreciated.

Comment: Please make sure that you have a "project.json" file. And are u using Jenkins as your build machine?

Comment: @yonBav I have a project.json file and am using MSBuild via TFS to do the builds.

Comment: This is a bit tricky cause it can be multiple things causing this. So sorry if i'm saying some obvious things. Make sure you have the vs 2015 tools installed. For farther info check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/39020289/5558375

Comment: @yonBav yes, done that too. What's is surprising that the path exists but the process says it doesn't.

Comment: Have you set SDK version in the `global.json` file, like `"sdk": { "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131" }`? And you can check if this issue occur with Visual Studio on the build machine.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT The project builds in VS2015 on the build machine.